# Can Noether's theorem be understood intuitively?

Tags: symmetry, conservation-laws, lagrangian-formalism, noethers-theorem

[Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) is one of those surprisingly clear results of mathematical calculations, for which I am inclined to think that some kind of intuitive understanding should or must be possible. However I don't know of any, do you?

> *Independence of time $\leftrightarrow$ energy conservation.
> *Independence of position $\leftrightarrow$ momentum conservation.
> *Independence of direction $\leftrightarrow$ angular momentum conservation.

I know that the mathematics leads in the direction of *Lie-algebra* and such but I would like to discuss whether this theorem can be understood from a non-mathematical point of view also.

Comment: @MBN especially because these results look so crystal clear, its almost a farce not to be able to explain them from a more common angle.

Comment: More on Noether's theorem and intuition: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19847/2451

Comment: I'd like to recommend a recent paper by John Baez which makes Noether's theorem a lot more intuitive (to me, a mathematician, at least) : https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.14741

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's intuitively clear that the energy most accurately describes how much the state of the system is changing with time. So if the laws of physics don't depend on time, then the amount how much the state of the system changes with time has to be conserved because it's still changing in the same way.

In the same way, and perhaps even more intuitively, if the laws don't depend on position, you may hit the objects, and hit them a little bit more, and so on. The momentum measures how much the objects depend on space, so if the laws themselves don't depend on the position on space, the momentum has to be conserved.

The angular momentum with respect to an axis is determining how much the state changes if you rotate it around the axis - how much it depends on the angle (therefore "angular" in the name). So the symmetry is linked to the conservation law once again.

If your intuition doesn't find the comments intuitive enough, maybe you should train your intuition because your current intuition apparently misses the most important properties of time, space, angles, energy, momentum, and angular momentum. ;-)

Comment: Ah, and what about other symmetries and the corresponding conserved quantities.

Comment: Dear @MBN, it's actually much more "intuitive" with all other examples because we usually learn the other symmetries during a heavily mathematical course - learning session - so even at the intuitive level, we know that those symmetries generate some quantities and are linked to conservation laws. For example, the electric charge is linked to the U(1) gauged symmetry because we know that this U(1) symmetry changes the phases of charged fields by an angle proportional to the charge.

Comment: So, if the laws of physics don't care about the angle - the phase of the charged fields - which is what it means for them to be symmetric, then it means that you may first change the phase, and then time-evolve, or first time-evolve, and then change the phase by the gauge transformation. It means that the initial and final states carry the same charge - change under the rotation: the charge is conserved because of the symmetry. Similarly, you may discuss the conservation of the SU(2) and SU(3) generators.

Comment: You may also think about the discrete counterpart of Noether's theorem. Take parity: it is the operator $P$ such that $P^2=+1$. Well, it may also be $-1$ but let me ignore those subtleties now. If the laws of physics are symmetric relatively to $\vec x \to -\vec x$, then it doesn't matter whether you first flip the orientation (mirror) and then time-evolve, or vice versa. This is equivalent to conserving parity as the quantum number because parity eigenstates are either even or odd under the reflection, and this even-ness or odd-ness - the parity :-) - is conserved in time evolution: tautology

Comment: I have two question to Lubosh: If something (L) does not depend on angle $\theta$, then the derivative of this something $dL/d\theta$ is zero. It has nothing to do with time derivative being zero. Next, the sum of masses in an ensemble of particles is also conserved quantity, even in the relativistic mechanics although it does not define the system mass (the system mass includes the interaction energy too). Can you comment it?

Comment: Lubos, I agree with you. It's just how I understand the question. Probably I am wrong, but to me it seems as the OP is asking about how a group of symmetries leads to a conserved quantity.

Comment: Symmetry with respect to some transformations is not the same thing as time-independence (conservation). The latter needs essentially the equations of motion.

Comment: This answer comes closest to what I was looking for, however the answer looks suspicious w.r.t. some cicular arguments e.g.: "it's intuitively clear that energy most accurately describes.." or "momentum measures..". These assumptions I would like to see clarified. The sentence "if the laws of physics don't depend on time, then the amount how much the state of the system changes with time has to be conserved" makes sense to me, but it is assumed that this amount is called 'energy', why? Same for momentum; note that when you hit objects, momentum is only conserved when you include the hitter.

Comment: @Gerard, perhaps you were asking too much for an answer without maths rather than asking for minimum maths. It's the symmetry of the action which gives rise to conserved quantities and you do need some maths to show this, just as you need minimum maths to explain what energy or momentum is.

Answer (score 14):

The intuitive argument for Noether's theorem, which is also the best completely precise argument for Noether's theorem, appears in Feynman's popular book "The Character of Physical Law". I will reproduce the argument which relies on the following diagram:

[image]

In this diagram the two parallel squiggles with a line connecting them at the top and at the bottom represent a particle path and a displaced particle path.

The action is stationary on the particle path, so the square squiggle which translates over, goes up parallel, and comes back has the same action as the original path. The original path, however, has the same action as *just the squiggle part* of the other path, therefore the two horizontal lines at top and bottom have equal action.

You can use this argument to find the exact form of the Noether current by replacing Feynmans horizontal lines with quick kicks by the momentum over a time $\epsilon$. His argument is an honest to goodness proof, it is by far the best proof, and it is the *only* case in all the history of publishing where a result is best presented in a popular book.

If you make the kicks continuous in time, so that they come here and there, you can still see that the kicks integrate by parts. This argument appears in the introduction to one of Hawking's 1970s papers, and is essentially equivalent to Feynman's "Character of Physical Law" argument, except it appears more than ten years later.

Comment: The image can be found [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BrYgE.jpg).  It was discussed in this [later Physics.SE question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19847/).

Comment: It's stupefying that people will do such mental gymnastics to avoid a simple calculation. (Especially when the simple calculation also pins down all the signs and factors etc.)

Answer (score 9):

Well, I don't know about any intuitive explanation besides intuition gained by understanding the underlying math (mainly differential geometry, Hamiltonian mechanics and group theory). So with the risk of not giving you quite what you want, I'll try to approach the problem mathematically.

If you know Hamiltonian mechanics then the statement of the theorem is exceedingly simple. Assume we have a Hamiltonian $H$. To this there is associated a unique Hamiltonian flow (i.e. a one-parameter family of symplectomorphisms -- which is just a fancy name for diffeomorphisms preserving the symplectic structure) $\Phi_H(t)$ on the manifold. From the point of view of Lie theory, the flow is a group action and there exists its generator (which is a vector field) $V_H$ (this can also be obtained from $\omega(\cdot, V_H) = dH$ with $\omega$ being the symplectic form). Now, the completely same stuff can be written for some other function $A$, with generator $V_A$ and flow $\Phi_A(s)$. Think of this $A$ as some conserved quantity and of $\Phi_A(s)$ as a continuous family of symmetries.

Now, starting from Hamiltonian equation ${{\rm d} A \over {\rm d} t} = \left\{A,H\right\}$ we see that if $A$ Poisson-commutes with $H$ it is conserved. Now, this is not the end of the story. From the second paragraph it should be clear that $A$ and $H$ don't differ that much. Actually, what if we swapped them? Then we'd get ${{\rm d} H \over {\rm d} s} = \left\{H,A\right\}$. So we see that $A$ is constant along Hamiltonian flow (i.e. conserved) if and only if $H$ is constant along the symmetry flow (i.e. the physical laws are symmetric).

So much for why the stuff works. Now, how do we get from symmetries to conserved quantities? This actually isn't hard at all but requires some knowledge of differential geometry. Let's start with most simple example.

#### Translation

This is a symmetry such that $x \to x^\prime = x + a$. You can imagine that we move our coordinates along the $x$ direction. With $a$ being a parameter, this is a symmetry flow. If we differentiate with respect to this parameter, we'll get a vector field. Here it'll be $\partial_x$ (i.e. constant vector field aiming in the direction $x$). Now, what function on the symplectic manifold does it correspond to? Easy, it must be $p$ because by differentiating this we'll get a constant 1-form field $dp$ and then we have to use $\omega$ to get a vector field $\partial_x$.

Other way to see that it must be $p$: suppose you have a wave $\exp(ipx)$. Then $\partial_x \exp(ipx) = ip \exp(ipx)$ so momentum and partial derivatives are morally the same thing. Here we're of course exploiting the similarity between Fourier transform (which connects $x$ and $p$ images) and symplectic structure (which combines $x$ and $p$).

#### Rotation

Now onto something a bit harder. Suppose we have a flow
$$\pmatrix{x \cr y} \to \pmatrix{x' \cr y'}=  \pmatrix{\cos(\phi) & \sin(\phi) \cr - \sin(\phi) & \cos(\phi)} \pmatrix {x \cr y} $$
This is of course a rotational flow. Here we'll get a field $y {\rm d}x - x {\rm d} y$ and the conserved quantity of the form $y p_x - x p_y$ which can in three dimensions be thought of as a third component of angular momentum $L_z$.

Note that the above was done mainly for illustrative purposes as we could have worked in polar coordinates and then it would be actually the same problem as the first one because we'd get the field $\partial_{\phi}$ and conserved quantity $p_{\phi}$ (which *is* angular momentum).

Comment: Marek wrote: "if A Poisson-commutes with H it is conserved". This is what I wrote in my comment: without equations of motion it is impossible to derive conservation laws. Independence of something with respect to rotations is not the same as independence of something else with respect to time!

Comment: @Vladimir: huh? Independence of Hamiltonian w.r.t. rotations is *exactly* the same as independence of angular momentum w.r.t. to evolution in time. In Hamiltonian formalism one can see this equivalence most clearly: there is no difference at all between $A$ and $H$ (or between their vector fields or flows). There is only the difference of semantics because we interpret one of those flows as time evolution. But that is put in by hand, it's not in the formalism itself.

Comment: To Marek: so you cannot do without equations of motion (Hamiltonian, Lagrangian), can you? It is easy to understand: if at some moment $t=t_1$ the system has some symmetry (for example, particles aligned along some axis), there is no guarantee that this symmetry will remain the same at other moments $t > t_1$: particles can fly away in 3D according to their equations and initial conditions.

Comment: @Vladimir: aren't you confusing the symmetry of initial conditions with the symmetry of physical laws? Symmetry of physical laws is expressed via invariance of Hamiltonian w.r.t. to the said symmetry and this can't change in time. Besides this, there can also be symmetry in initial condition. But there is no theorem that would imply that the symmetry of the initial conditions has to be conserved. And it indeed doesn't have to be.

Comment: Marek, tell me clearly, without symmetries there is no integrals of motion? What new do symmetries bring in this respect?

Comment: @Vladimir: I am not quite sure what you are asking but symmetries help reduce the number of degrees of freedom. In general there $2N$ independent functions on the phase space that you have to solve for. If you succeed in finding enough integrals of motion then you have correspondingly less equations to solve.

Comment: By the way, why the down-votes? I am quite confident this answer is correct, so I suppose it's because it seems too mathematical and off-topic? If you think it is off-topic, please up-vote this comment and I'll delete this answer if this comment gets enough up-votes.

Comment: Marek, only constraints reduce the number of independent variables and thus that of solutions. Symmetries **simplify** some expressions (solutions) but do not reduce the number of independent variables! It is like passing from the expression a+ab+b to a+b.

Comment: It's a nice answer that people, like myself can learn from, but not intutive enough as was requested in the question. If you could add an intutitive section right at the beginning which minimizes the maths, then it would be an improvement. I think the questioner needs to be told that it's the symmetry of the Lagrangian that leads to conserved quantities, with a brief description of what one is for a simple mechanical system as an example.

Comment: @John: I'll think about it but as I've said I am not sure about how to make it more intuitive. In particular, I don't have any magical picture in my head that would make everything obvious. I just imagine the flows and their generators but this probably can't be described without math.

Comment: To John McVirgo: are my examples "enlightening"?

Comment: @Marek, Lubos has already given a non mathematical answer so it would be nice if you could expand on it a touch mathematically for two masses on the end of a spring as an example. Stating L = T - V, explaining what the terms and action are. Then showing how the invariance of this action under some transformations gives rise to the various conserved quantites. Of course, all this takes time, but will be an investment when teaching students, if you decide to;) Teaching is an underrated discipline that requries investing in the development of communications skills.

Comment: @John: I'd be glad to provide such an example (although it would require Lagrangian formalism and completely new answer) but it's not clear to me that it also wouldn't be down-voted by the same people. This question explicitly asks for non-mathematical description (whether it's possible or not), so I'll respect it and won't provide another mathematical answer (and probably will also delete this one too).

Comment: Haven't seen the word *morally* used in physics before, only in the math community. :)

Answer (score 7):

I can only tell that those conserved quantities you have listed above are additive in particles: $P = \sum p_i(t)$, for example. But there are those that are not additive! They do not have special names.

For N differential equations there are as many integrals of motion as the initial conditions or so. Some of them can be casted sometimes in the additive form but generally (when there are no symmetries) the total number of integrals of motion remains the same. They all are simply non additive (more messy, if you like). So I would answer that symmetries help combine some integrals of motion as conserved quantities additive in all particles.

EDIT 1: Maybe Noether's theorem shows explicitly what the conserved quantities are whereas from equations it may be not so evident to derive?

EDIT 2: I got -4. Is my reasoning really that bad?

EDIT 3: a page from Landau:

[image: Conservation Laws]

EDIT 4: An example of integrals of motion:

[image: 1D Integrals of motion]

Comment: Donwvoters, please give your disagreement statements.

Comment: This didn't answer the question. How does it relate to Noether's theorem?

Comment: It didn't answer the question, and I suspect it is intended as trolling.

Comment: To Peter: Yes, I clearly wrote that symmetries help construct less messy (simpler than in general case) conserved quantities. I think for intuitive understanding it is sufficient.

Comment: To Colin K: do you think I like to collect downvotes? I write sincerely what I think, that's it. Am I wrong when I do so?

Comment: Yes, there are always as many integrals of motion as equations; e. g. the initial conditions are integrals of motion in the sense that X(X_0, -t) = X_0. However, they are not _isolating_ integrals, and therefore they are less "useful". Symmetries always yield isolating integrals (IIRC).

Comment: To Platypus Lover: Yes, that's what I mean. Why Marek wants to execute me - I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks, Marek, for your sincere answer. I really appreciate it. I hate anonymous votes because I learn nothing from them. I am here not only to teach but also to learn. If you could explain what is wrong in my answer, it would be helpful to all of readers.

Comment: By the way, Marek, you have so many votes! Maybe you will be more specific in critics of my posts? I need specific answers and explanations rather than just your hate, you know.

Comment: I didn't down vote your answer either, but don't you see it is not answering the actual question. Imagine for a moment you are the person who asked the question (and read the question), do you think your answer helps him?!

Comment: I did my best and I also asked Gerard directly if my answer was helpful.

Comment: @Vladimir, the question and Lubos's answer was clear and intuitive, Marek's too technical for me, but worth looking in to because of it's organisation. Yours, on the other hand, lacks structure, coherence and hence credibility even though you may be trying to say something profound, or... jibberish. Maybe you see this as a points competition and answering questions you can't, or maybe you're sincere.

Comment: I have a suggestion.   Lets think of question(s) we can ask on Math.stackexchange to help clear all this up.   Something like "What is the difference between integrals of motion as equations and  isolating integrals? Do Noetherian Symmetries always yield isolating integrals?  Why?   What is the connection between additive symmetries (in particles) and Noetherian symmetries?"   Let the mathematicians sort it out.  Furthermore they are very polite.   In a way, it is like going back to school.   So this comment is a request to help perfect the question(s) we or I might ask on math.stackexchange

Comment: @Vladimir in this particular answer I see nothing wrong except that it is not clear for the questioner. This is an "error" people whose first language is not english may make, as happens with me too. Unfortunately, because often you come up with a pov perpendicular to the generally accepted one you  raise the ire of people  just by seeing your name. I raised this issue in meta, http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414/can-voting-anonymously-and-without-comment-lead-to-consensus-science . People are mammals, and mammals are herd animals or pack animals, group reactions both.

Comment: I do not mind to get downvotes but I am here also to learn so I would love to understand my errors.

Comment: To John McVirgo: The original question was not technical but intuitive so I tried to simplify my explanation as much as possible. I was sincere. Concerning Lubosh's answer, there is a missing thing in it: I asked Lubosh above and I repeat it here: If something (L(t)) does not depend on angle θ, then the derivative of this something dL/dθ is zero. It has nothing to do with **time** derivative being zero. So there is no direct evidence of conservation in case of symmetry. One has to employ the equations of motion to prove that one thing leads to another.

Comment: Okay @Vladimir, so to the statement of what's wrong: "For N differential equations there are as many integrals of motion as the initial conditions or so." -> complete rubbish. Integrals of motion have nothing to do with initial conditions. In particular, if the system has no symmetry at all, then there can't ever be a conserved quantity. In other words, there is no non-trivial function on the phase space that would be invariant w.r.t. Hamiltonian flow. The system which *do* have enough symmetries (and therefore conserved quantities) are called integrable (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Of course, integrable systems are very special. Just consider that three-body problem *is not* an integrable system (not even that, it's chaotic). It can be shown (as was done by Poincaré 100 years ago) that you can't construct enough integrals of motion (besides the usual energy, momentum, etc.) for the three-body problem. The analysis is subtle and non-trivial. Nevertheless, general system has basically no conserved quantities.

Comment: If you want to learn more about this stuff, you can start e.g. here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6379/what-is-an-integrable-system

Comment: Marek, you make an impression that a tree body problem has no solutions, that is is useless to solve the equations numerically because of unpredictable chaos, etc., etc. It is not the case. Integrals of motion (= solutions) exist without symmetries and of course they are expressed via independent initial conditions. Read Landau textbook on Classical mechanics, I learned this material from it.

Comment: Vladimir.  Please cite the pages or sentences in Landau's book to which you are referring.   Of course integrals of motion are not just numerical solutions.   Are you implying that they somehow are?

Comment: To sigoldberg1: I added a page scan to my answer above.

Comment: +1. And here's why. Not because I have any desire to be contrarian for the fun of it. But I think that @Vladimir, despite the extremely negative reception some of his questions and answers have received, is fundamentally sincere at some level. I also think that English is not @Vladimir's native language. This should have been apparent from the get-go but it can take time for such distinctions to filter in, especially in a non-verbal setting. Admittedly he has not helped his situation by coming on a bit too "strong". But perhaps such courage is an admirable trait rather than a deficit (contd)

Comment: As for the answer itself. @Vladimir makes a perfectly valid point that it is important to all constants of motions are not "created equal". In particular, those which derive from a space-time symmetry are of greater value because they are extensive quantities such as momentum and angular momentum. *However*, there do exists integrals of motion which are *non-additive* or *non-extensive* for certain systems (contd)

Comment: I think the best example of this is in field theories in 2+1 or 1+1 dimensions, where there exist **many integrable** models (see Baxter's book) which have an **infinite** number of conserved quantities. In such cases Noether's theorem might not tell us everything about the conserved quantities (*not* symmetries) which can be used to characterize a system.

Comment: @space_cadet  1. Creationists are "fundamentally sincere" too. 2. This is completely not the answer to the question and if one wants to show off he must go to exhibition.  3. I don't think that the statement is correct *in modern terminology*. But I'm not discussing it here.

Comment: Kostya wrote: "I don't think that the statement is correct in modern terminology. But I'm not discussing it here." No, Kostya, you don't. You tell the truth on me instead.

Comment: @Kostya I don't think snide comments and name-calling are helpful to proving your side of the story. Anger doesn't work. Not even against creationists ;)

Comment: I am removing the down-vote as it's become obvious that you are talking just about integration constants. I am not sure why Landau calls them integrals of motion but this is definitely not a standard terminology, so I suggest you use more common term of "integration constants".

Comment: But in any case, this answer is still off-topic as these integration constants are just a basic topic in the differential calculus and in particular have no bearing on symmetries, solvability of the system, etc. For that the term integral of motion (or constant of motion) is important and there can definitely be less than $2s$ of them.

Comment: Landau clearly says that some combinations of dynamical variables do not change in time, and to make it evident, he relates them with the integration constants (=initial data).

Comment: To Kostya and Marek: I added an example of integrals of motion to my answer.

Comment: Marek, at least in the literature in Russian, integrals of motion is the standard terminology.

Comment: @Vladimir, is your answer"enlightening"? It's a lot clearer now and looks interesting, but doesn't mention anything about the invariance of the action, or Noether's theorem which are related to the question asked.

Comment: Well, Vladimir's question/answer is now clearer to me.  He apparently wants to know the relationship between Noether's therem and what Landau calls additive, conserved quantities.   Relating it back to the original question, what parts of Noether's Thm. imply that the resultant integrals of motion are additive?   This obviously relates to the intuitive understanding of the theorem and its interpretation, assuming the above is true.

Comment: Marek wrote: "if the system has no symmetry at all, then there can't ever be a conserved quantity. In other words, there is no non-trivial function on the phase space that would be invariant w.r.t. Hamiltonian flow." And I Vladimir Kalitvianski provide an example of the contrary. See EDIT 4 of my answer, Marek.

Comment: @Vladimir: I think I understand why people are downvoting. Your answer is technically correct, and is interesting, but you've failed to appreciate what the question was, so your answer does not help the questioner. (At least I, and it seems others) understood the question to mean intuitively understanding the pairings --- e.g. why momentum goes with translation invariance. Your answer simply does not address this point. Perhaps this is a language problem --- my local Russian expert often answers my question completely tangentially too and instead tells me something interesting but unhelpful.

Comment: @genneth: I do not care for downvotes. My answers are often complementary to other answers. Sometimes I see people are too narrow-minded like in case of conservation laws. Often they do not understand variety and ambiguity of this question. For example, conservation of the total momentum is written as $\vec{P}=const$. It is three scalar conservation laws. Any combination of them is also a conservation law, etc. I am afraid there is no explanation of pairing except for, maybe, a tautology.

Comment: @Vladimir: I agree --- it's good to bring a little extra to the table --- I like to do it too. If you do however, make sure your answer is not the first one to appear --- wait for a good, clean answer which is classically correct; also, in your answer, at the top, make clear that you think that other answer answers the question, but that you would like to add a little extra to the topic, which is possibly tangential. People seem to respond better once they realise you're not saying that the correct answer is wrong, but just adding to it.

Answer (score 6):

Here are my two cents. Read the proof it will help you understand and build intuition because it is constructive. It explicitly shows you what the conserved quantity is, given the group of symmetries. If it is too hard to follow and you can't see the forest because of the trees, try a few examples it should help. Also here is a link that may help a bit.

http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/noether.html

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a mathematical theorem whose physical content you know already, it is difficult to discuss it without mathematics. But still I will try to present it in a simple way. It may help if we understand how it is derived.

Generally we look for an invariance of the action under a symmetry transformation with a time independent parameter. This is then a trivial mathematical identity. Now it is observed that if the dynamical variables obey the equations of motions then action becomes stationary even if the parameter is time dependent. We observe that the variation of the action - which must be zero since the action is stationary - can only depend on the integration of the time derivatives of the parameter.  Now integrate by parts to take all the time derivatives off it and keep the rest in the integrand. Since the parameter is arbitrary, its co efficient in the integral must be zero. Now this coefficient is time derivative of something whose time derivative is zero. Therefore this "something" is constant or conserved in time.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a quick look at the answers and I think a point is being systematically missed.

Noether's theorem is a *definition* of the conserved quantity associated to a symmetry, *plus* a proof that the equations of motion indeed imply conservation of said quantity under time evolution. (This is conceptually similar to how Newton's first law of motion is a definition of inertial frames.)

OP writes

> *Independence of time ↔ energy conservation

which should be understood as

> *Independence of time ↔ there exists a conserved quantity E, which we have agreed to call "energy".

---

The "Noether trick" approach to the theorem (actually relevant for calculations) also appears to be absent. For completeness, I will illustrate it for
$$
S=\int dt\; \tfrac{1}{2} \dot q(t)^2.
$$
Say you want the conserved quantity associated to time translations $q(t)\to q(t+\varepsilon \Delta t)$ for $\varepsilon \in[0,1)$ and $\Delta t$ an arbitrary time interval (being absolutely precise here). Since
$$
\exp(\varepsilon \Delta t\;\partial/\partial t) q(t)=q(t+\varepsilon (\Delta t))
$$
we understand the infinitesimal generator is the operator
$$
\delta_\varepsilon=\varepsilon \Delta t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}
$$
(This is essentially Taylor's theorem.) This is a variation, so
$$
\label{blah}
\delta_\varepsilon S=\int dt\; \dot{q}\delta_\varepsilon \dot q= \int dt\;\dot q \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\varepsilon \Delta t \dot q)\,, \quad (\star)
$$
This is obviously the integral of a total $\partial/\partial t$ derivative, so $\delta_\varepsilon S=0$.

The Noether trick is to calculate $(\star)$ with the replacement $$\varepsilon\to\varepsilon(t)$$ (satisfying correct boundary conditions etc.). I find
$$\delta_{\varepsilon(t)} S=\int dt\;\dot q \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(\varepsilon \Delta t \dot q) =-\Delta t\int dt\; \ddot q \dot q \varepsilon=-\Delta t\int dt\;\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big(\frac{\dot q^2}{2}\Big) \varepsilon. $$
Since $\delta_{\varepsilon(t)} q$ preserves the boundary conditions, $\delta_{\varepsilon(t)} S$ must vanish whenever the equations of motion hold. Therefore
$$ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Big(\frac{\dot q^2}{2}\Big)=0
$$
when the equations of motion hold.

We read off the conserved quantity "kinetic energy"
$$
T=\Big(\frac{\dot q^2}{2}\Big).
$$

The role of time independence is to arrange that after you remove all derivatives from $\varepsilon$ via integration by parts, its coefficient turns into a total time derivative.

See [Townsend](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.07128) (from whom I learned this) for more details.