# Symmetry of physical laws

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, time, symmetry, noethers-theorem

What is the easiest explanation for how the symmetry of laws under translation in time relates to energy conservation in physics?

Comment: [Noether's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether's_theorem).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Noether Theorem and Energy conservation in classical mechanics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94381/2451)

Comment: IMO, this comes the closest to [Can Noether's theorem be understood intuitively?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4959/)